# Automatically paste a copied text on clipboard to a textbox

Tags: vba, textbox, copy-paste, userform

I was wondering if it is possible to automatically paste a copied text to a textbox once clicked.

For example:
IF I copy(ctrl+c) a series of numbers from a notepad, once I go to my workform and click on the blank text box it will automatically paste(ctrl+v) copied numbers on the box

Answer (score 0):

If the values are in your clipboard you can implement the following function:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Paste
End Sub
```

This will paste the content of your clipboard into the text box when you are entering the text box.

Comment: It works but the problem is, when it automatically paste the clipboard content once the userform that contains the textbox initializes. What I was hoping to do is to only paste the content once the textbox is clicked.

Comment: That's not in your question. So it's not in my answer.